# NodaTime Instant serializes as "Ticks" from Xamarin Android project, "ticks" from Win32

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin, nodatime

I have an Xamarin project which I'm developing. Most of the code is in C#, in portable class libraries. It uses an Azure DocumentDb database for data storage.

I do most of my development / debug using a Win32 client, and then do final debug / testing in an Android client.

I'm using NodaTime v1.34 and NodaTime.Serializer.JsonNet v1.32 and Visual Studio 2017.

When I serialize a NodaTime Instant, it has a tag of "Ticks" in the Android project, "ticks" in the Win32 project. This causes an exception when loading the data from Win32 (if it was save from Android).

Any ideas why?

Or, is there a way to tell the Json serializer to ignore case?

Comment: I would file a bug with the NodaTime team

Comment: It sounds like you haven't wired up the serializer properly, as it should show an ISO8601 timestamp, not ticks.  Did you call `ConfigureForNodaTime` on your `JsonSerializer` or `JsonSerializerSettings`?

Comment: @Matt Johnson Thanks, I tried that also. When I hook in ConfigureForNodaTime I get a different error: 
An unhandled exception of type 'NodaTime.Utility.InvalidNodaDataException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
Unexpected token parsing Instant. Expected String, got Date.
And setting serializerSettings.DateParseHandling to DateParseHandling.None still does not fix it.
I'm guessing the DocumentDb serializer is not using or is overwriting JsonConvert.DefaultSettings.

Comment: I suggest you try to find the settings that `DocumentDb` *is* using and configure those instead. You definitely want to be using the NodaTime-supplied settings.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Thanks. DocumentDb does not currently have any json configuration options - it's a (large) open request to their team. For my persistent classes, I have now added a simple wrapper struct to the Instant, Duration, LocalTime, and LocalDate types.